# SQL average count postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, average

I want to find out what is the average number from table column entries (for example reservations) per year(0-10 years ago, 10-20 years ago, 20+ years ago). I know how to do the average part but I don't know how to categorize the AVG in the different group years.

i have this code

```
SELECT DATE_OF_RESERVATION,count(RESERVATIONID) AS RESERVATIONS
FROM RESERVATIONS
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Date) - DATE_OF_RESERVATION <= 10
GROUP BY DATE_OF_RESERVATION
```

This is the code for only one category (the first). I want to do this for all three at the same query but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression.  For instance:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Date) - DATE_OF_RESERVATION < 10
             THEN '[0-10)'
             WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Date) - DATE_OF_RESERVATION < 20
             THEN '[0-20)'
             WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Current_Date) - DATE_OF_RESERVATION < 30
             THEN '[0-30)'
             ELSE 'More'
        END) as grp,
       COUNT(*) AS RESERVATIONS
FROM RESERVATIONS
GROUP BY grp;
```

Comment: there is an issue with {COUNT(*)}
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COUNT"
LINE 9:        COUNT(*)